# Can Bluetooth OBEXD execute a script after it was transferred?

Tags: bluetooth, obex

I want to transfer a shell script (or whatever format) from an adroid to a bluetooth device.

I see in the OBEX help command

```
Usage:
  obexd [OPTION...]

Help Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help options

Application Options:
  -d, --debug=DEBUG           Enable debug information output
  -p, --plugin=NAME,...       Specify plugins to load
  -P, --noplugin=NAME,...     Specify plugins not to load
  -n, --nodetach              Run with logging in foreground
  -r, --root=PATH             Specify root folder location. Both absolute and relative can be used, but relative paths are assumed to be relative to user $HOME folder. Default $XDG_CACHE_HOME
  -S, --root-setup=SCRIPT     Root folder setup script
  -l, --symlinks              Allow symlinks leading outside of the root folder
  -c, --capability=FILE       Specify capability file, use '!' mark for scripts
  -a, --auto-accept           Automatically accept push requests
```

some sections about allowing scripts to be transferred. They can be also executed after they are transferred by the same OBEXD? I see in their git source something about that:

https://github.com/sragavan/obex/blob/master/src/main.c#L319

Thank you